# SlimFramework Changing global var inside route

Tags: php, scope, routes, global, slim

Example code:

```
$price = 75;

$app->post('/update/price', function() use ($price) { 
    $price += 20; 
});
```

In Slim everytime when I trigger the ajax the global price is always 75. How can I change the global price from my route (change the scope)?
I've searched slim forum but there is only answer like : use db, cookies, cache etc. I would like to use something more elegant

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct. Can you just tell me the output of my code? So I can figure out what's gonna wrong with your code. May be your request is not matching with this route.

```php
$price = 75;

$app->post('/update/price', function() use ($price) { 
    $price += 20;
    var_dump($price); die();
});
```